# Suddenly my font looks worse

Tags: fonts, screen, gui

I have been using Source Sans Pro in Ubuntu 23.04 without problem.
Suddenly, font changed its readability for the system but not in the browser.
I would like to know how to fix it.

I'm thinking it may be one of these reasons:

a) Updating changed something (updates hadn't been working for some time so I clicked 'default' in the 'Authentication tab in Updates manager)

b) changing the icon theme changed something (but it doesn't work again when reversed)

c) Unintentionally I changed fonts configuration. To me it seems unchanged (I attach a capture with the current configuration)

d) Some tweaks that I had done via terminal, which I can't remember, in order to improve them no longer work.

- My current fonts configuration:

  [image: My current fonts configuration]
- The font looked this way everywhere, not only in Chrome. For me, this is the good way:

  [image: The font looked this way everywhere, not only in Chrome. For me, this is the good way]
- The font started looking that way across different parts in the system:

  [image: The font started looking that way across different parts in the system]

Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There were so many problems and I am too new to the system to solve them, so I decided to reinstall everything and bear in mind not to do strange things this time.